# Asp Focus on input jumping bug

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I've got a web form using asp.net. In this form I have a lot of inputs.
For one of the drop downs whenever you press it, the focus jumps to the next text box.

This is in a update panel, because there is some server side work required for filtering, hiding, etc.

If the User chooses Australia from `visaType_filter` then it hides `visaType_dd` and shows `visaType_tb`.  If they choose NZ its the other way around.

Now my question:

Is there a bug or something that makes focus jump off of a drop down when you click on it to go to the next input (or control)?

Code:

```
<fieldset>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="visaTypeUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <label>Visa Type Number</label>
            <label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="visaType_filter" runat="server" Width="40%" OnSelectedIndexChanged="visaType_filter_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                <asp:TextBox ID="visaType_tb" runat="server" Width="40%" OnTextChanged="visaType_tb_blur" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="visaType_dd" runat="server" Width="40%"/>
                <asp:Literal ID="visaType_literal" runat="server" />
            </label>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using jQuery and Ajax in place of `UpdatePanels`.

Comment: Hi @CubeJockey. Apologies on behalf of my previous self, I did not think to explain my answer.
4 years later now, I cannot remember how I did this. I don't even use ASP.NET any more :(

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, when UpdatePanel gets triggered, the focus does not get maintained. So ideally, you shouldn't be getting any focus at all.

Regardless of reason, you can work-around the issue using [ScriptManager.SetFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb156188.aspx) method to maintain focus on the drop-down.

You can also have client side solutions for maintaining focus - they essentially work by hooking into AJAX requests to remember the focused control before update panel is triggered and then restoring it back when update panel post-back is completed: see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/PageRequestManager.aspx) for one such solution.