# How to prevent the Focus() method from scrolling the page to the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, ajax

I have set of textboxes in a gridview and  I use the `Focus()` method to restore the focus after losing to the intended text box. The problem is :

The page (scrollable) and when I call the Focus method, in the text changed event, the page jump to the top. It's such a confusing behavior.

My question is:

Is there some way to prevent the `Focus()` method from jumping the page to the top?

My code:

```
protected void txt_evaluateWeights_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            calc();
            int index = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow)(((RadTextBox)sender).Parent.NamingContainer)).DataItemIndex;

            ((RadTextBox)gv_Evaluation.Rows[index + 1].Cells[3].FindControl("txt_evaluateWeights")).Focus();//Here is the problem. 
        }
```

**Note:**

- I use the `asp:TextBox`, and the same problem.
- My grid view in an update panel

---

**EDIT :**

**Javascript workaround:**

```
var lastFocusedControlId = "";

function focusHandler(e) {
    document.activeElement = e.originalTarget;
}

function appInit() {
    if (typeof (window.addEventListener) !== "undefined") {
        window.addEventListener("focus", focusHandler, true);
    }
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(pageLoadingHandler);
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(pageLoadedHandler);
}

function pageLoadingHandler(sender, args) {
    lastFocusedControlId = typeof (document.activeElement) === "undefined"
        ? "" : document.activeElement.id;
}

function focusControl(targetControl) {
    if (Sys.Browser.agent === Sys.Browser.InternetExplorer) {
        var focusTarget = targetControl;
        if (focusTarget && (typeof (focusTarget.contentEditable) !== "undefined")) {
            oldContentEditableSetting = focusTarget.contentEditable;
            focusTarget.contentEditable = false;
        }
        else {
            focusTarget = null;
        }
        try {
            targetControl.focus();
            if (focusTarget) {
                focusTarget.contentEditable = oldContentEditableSetting;
            }
        }
        catch (err) { }
    }
    else {
        targetControl.focus();
    }

}

function pageLoadedHandler(sender, args) {
    if (typeof (lastFocusedControlId) !== "undefined" && lastFocusedControlId != "") {
        var newFocused = $get(lastFocusedControlId);
        if (newFocused) {
            focusControl(newFocused);
        }
    }
}

Sys.Application.add_init(appInit);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to fix the way the Focus method behaves, there is an alternative.  I haven't tried it, but [this page has a discussion of the problem](http://couldbedone.blogspot.com/2007/08/restoring-lost-focus-in-update-panel.html), and some client-side javascript to remember which control had the focus, and then put the focus back on that object after the UpdatePanel gets refreshed. Be sure to read the comment for some updates to the script.

If you use this method, you would remove the call to Focus on in your codebehind, and let this script deal with it on the client.

Comment: Thank us soooo much for this great solution .I edit my question ,Did you recommend any enhancement to this code?

Comment: I can't see any problems with it at the moment (haven't actually used it). So if it works okay for you in different browsers, then I'd leave it alone.

Comment: but what `===` does mean in javascript?

Comment: Not a typo. That means that it checks that the two values are the same and that they are also the same type. So, for example, 1=="1" is true, but 1==="1" is false.

Answer (score 4):

Provided that you're using update panels and jquery, the solution is quite straightforward. Let's say your textbox ID is tbDeliveryCost. Instead of using tbDeliveryCost.Focus(), do this:

```
string script = string.Format("$('#{0}').focus();", tbDeliveryCost.ClientID);
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "SetFocus", script, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack option:

```
<%@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) to scroll to your textbox:

```
$(...).scrollTo( $('<%= txt_evaluateWeights.ClientID %>') )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this after you set focus

```
Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>$(...).scollTo( $('<%= txt_evaluateWeights.ClientID %>') )
</script>");
```

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked a [zi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699171/asp-net-validation-summary-causes-page-to-jump-to-top)[lli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448962/scroll-go-to-the-top-page)[on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449174/prevent-go-to-the-top-page) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6853252/asp-focus-on-input-jumping-bug).

It's a bug in ASP.NET's JS library and the workaround is hacky:

```
var oldScroll = window.scrollTo;
window.scrollTo = function(){};

//... the ugly ASP.NET stuff

window.scrollTo = oldScroll;
```

The definitive solution to this is to stop using Microsoft ASP.NET and start using a decent technology that allows *you* to script the client side.

Comment: hmmm , Do u consider asp.net not a decent tech??!!

Comment: It's definitely not worth the money. =)

Comment: but what i know is `SOF` is built with this tech .

Comment: I still wouldn't recommend it to anybody

Comment: For the record, Stack Overflow is built with ASP.NET MVC, which is nothing like using WebForms with UpdatePanels.